# Define a multiple bar in Bootstrap for daytime representation

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to define a horizontal bar with multiple intervals. I try to start to:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xcesco/aq9Laaew/256069/)

The result is

[image: Simple progress bar in bootstrap]

What I need is to represent a day with multiple intervals. The day bar must have some label to show just the hours. Each interval must have a label inside. Just because an image is better than a thousand words:

[image: day bar with some intervals]

How can I achieve this goal? Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Hope this will help [Bootstrap4-multiple-bars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/progress/#multiple-bars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transparent progress bar intervals for the "empty" time slots. The labels outside the progress bar are entirely up to you as this is not something Bootstrap provides.

```
 <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-transparent" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">8:30-12:00</div>
        <div class="progress-bar bg-transparent" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">15:00-18:00</div>
 </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/A9mNyW8geC